# Calling fun inside constructor in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

hi guys i'm new in Koltin , in java we can do that

```
class A{
   int x;
   int y;
   A(int x, int y){
    this.x=x;
     this.y=y
   }
}

class B extends A{  
    int x,y;   
    B(int a, int b){
        super(x,getSum(x,y));
     }
   int getSum(int x, int y){
       return x+y;
    }
}
```

how can i do this code in Kotlin ,thank's for help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IntelliJ IDE's **Convert Java file to Kotlin file** feature, here is corresponding kotlin file.

test.kt:

```
internal class A(var x: Int, var y: Int)

internal class B(a: Int, b: Int) : A(x, getSum(x, y)) {
    var x: Int = 0
    var y: Int = 0
    fun getSum(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
        return x + y
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you use an `init` block, or a secondary constructor.

```
class ExampleOne(val myProperty: Int) {
    init {
        // insert code here
    }
}

class ExampleTwo {
    constructor(myParameter: Int) {
        // insert code here
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)

Answer (score -1):

This is no valid Java code since you cannot call `getSum` before `super` has been called in `super(x,getSum(x,y));`. This won't compile.

The easiest way to provide that behaviour in Kotlin, looks like this:

```
open class A(val a: Int, val b: Int)

class B(a: Int, b: Int) : A(a, a + b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use `companion object` to make your function static

```
internal class A(var x: Int, var y: Int)

internal class B(a: Int, b: Int) : A(a, getSum(a, b)) {
    
    companion object {
        fun getSum(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
            return x + y
        }
    }
}
```

It works a treat